# Drop down box and checklist settings

Tags: axure

In [Axure RP 8 Pro](https://www.axure.com/features/new-in-8), it seems that there is almost no stylistic options for drop down boxes and checklists. For example the tick box on the checklist is very small and I would like to make it lager.How do I access those functions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried their own technical support / forums? https://www.axure.com/c/forum.php

Comment: I just started using axure, but from what I understand - the input elements (such as dropdowns) will just take on the native webkit of whatever browser you view the preview of your wireframe in so that you can see true interactivity - so it likely won't matter much (i.e. chrome has it's own style for dropdowns vs. firefox)

Answer (score 1):

The default widgets provided in Axure RP Pro for standard web components are not flexible enough.

You can not modify style them enough. Additionally they have alignment issues.

How does a default checkbox widget look in Axure

[image: Checkbox Widget in Axure]

and in Axobe XD

[image: Checkbox Widget in Adobe XD]

The text alignment of the checkbox is just not precise.

**Solution**

In Axure, if you are not happy with the visual / behaviour of default widgets. We need to create a custom widgets.

**How to Create such custom Widgets**

Axure RP training site has detailed steps on how to create [Custom Checkbox and Radio Button](https://www.axure.com/support/training/custom-checkbox-radio-button-tutorial)

This will allow you to create your custom checkboxes and radio buttons that satisfy the visual appeal. However, beware that some options like treating them like a radio-group will need you to have a more complex interaction.

**Use an existing library and modify**

Additionally, if you want to save some time. You could use one of many Axure Libraries and modify the components from that.

Example: SAP Fiori Axure Library which provides Interactive as well as static components.

[image: Checkbox Widgets in SAP Fiori Widget library]

[SAP Fiori Axure Library Download link](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/09/Design-Stencils-Version-1.50_External.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I avoid drop downs and text field entries due to wanting to control the styling completely. My environment is not native, we do everything in HTML, we do use some native components, but generally it's web based.

I create mock-ups as part of the design process. If they're just used for reference and you have a style system/guide, then it's easier to role your own.

When I do a click through, I tend to animate the entry of the fields. The point being you just want to test concepts, not the ability of the user to use native controls like keyboards or scroll wheels. You just want to test concepts and usability of your design, not usability of the platform's controls.

For the drop down, I use a hidden Dynamic Panel. You can toggle visibility of the panel when an *on click* event occurs on the field for rectangle representing the drop down. Just specify animate slide up/down and your good to go. You can then do your own styling for mouse over, mouse press, disabled, selected, etc for both the drop down field and the drop down selection list.